# Blank FROM clause in JPQL?

Tags: sql, jpa, jpql

I'm using a JPQL select to access a Oracle DB function: `select FUNCTION('function_name', 'foo', 1234) from com_mycompany_bar obj`

This works as expected and the function is indeed called. The thing is I actually don't need the `FROM` clause and would rather have it empty instead of having to access an entity just to conform to the syntax.

What is the best option I have here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with JPQL, but can you not just omit the `From` clause entirely?  `select FUNCTION('function_name', 'foo', 1234)`?

Comment: @Siyual Good idea, but unfortunately JPQL demands a FROM clause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see several possible answers:

Within standard JPA there are two options, both involving Oracle `DUAL` "table"

1. Map `DUAL` to an entity and use it in the `FROM` clause. It is the more "JPQL" way, but it is more involved:

In Java code:

```
@Entity(name = "Dual")
@Table(name = "SYS.DUAL")
public class Dual {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "DUMMY")
    private String dummy;
}
```

In orm.xml:

```
<named-query name="yourQuery">
    <query><![CDATA[
        SELECT FUNCTION('function_name', 'foo', 1234) FROM Dual d
    ]]>
    </query>
</named-query>
```

In client code:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNamedQuery("yourQuery");
```

2. Just use a native query that uses `DUAL`

In orm.xml:

```
<named-native-query name="yourQuery">
    <query><![CDATA[
        SELECT function_name('foo', 1234) from sys.dual
    ]]>
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

In client code:

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("yourQuery");
```

As a last option, you can use some JPA implementation extension to JPA and avoid `DUAL`:

- Eclipselink:

  - http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/StoredProcedures
  - http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_namedstoredprocedurequery.htm
  - http://ronaldoblanc.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/jpa-eclipselink-and-complex-parameters.html
- Hibernate:

  - http://objectopia.com/2009/06/26/calling-stored-procedures-in-jpa/
  - [jpa calling stored procedure with output cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386777/jpa-calling-stored-procedure-with-output-cursor)
  - [How to call Oracle Function or Procedure using Hibernate 4 (EntityManager) or JPA 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335939/how-to-call-oracle-function-or-procedure-using-hibernate-4-entitymanager-or-jp)

Comment: great solution,ty very much.

Answer (score 1):

In short: *I don't think it's possible to skip FROM clause of JPQL query*.

JPQL grammar *requires* FROM clause to be present (see e.g. [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL_BNF#Select) or [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html)).

Calling stored procedures/functions is typically done via native queries (see: [createNativeQuery](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery(java.lang.String))). So this should work:

```
em.createNativeQuery("select function_name('foo', 1234)").getSingleResult()
```

UPDATE (from comments):

That's true that JPA native queries don't support named parameters. So you must decide which is the lesser of two evils for you: either using JPQL with unnecessary entity reference or native query with positional parameters instead of named.

But be aware that FUNCTION is EclipseLink extension so it won't work should you decide to change a vendor.

Comment: I know it is possible to do it with native query. StoredProcedureQuery doesn't work for *functions*, only for *procedures*.

Comment: @Roland So what is the reason that you can't use native query and have to use JPQL query? It looks that you are just picking the wrong tool to do the job.

Comment: Native queries don't allow named parameters, only positional parameters.

Comment: Oh, I see. It seems to me that you must pick lesser of two evils: either use JPQL with unnecessary entity reference or native query with positional parameters instead of named. PS. The third option is to use `(Session)em.getDelegate()` (if you use Hibernate under the hood) and invoke native query from Hibernate where named parameters are supported (see: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13930). But that seems even worse.

Comment: Exactly. It would also be possible to map DUAL as an entity(see other answer) but that looks like overkill.